# Beyond Compare tool to handle two files with same content but in different alignment

Tags: beyondcompare

I have a question regarding the "Beyond Compare" tool.
I have two text files with the same content but the content is in a different alignment in the two files:

Example:

```
File1 is as below:-            File2 is as below:- 

t1                             t1
t2                             t2
t20                            t100
t10                            t20
t100                           t10
```

when I compare these two files, the Beyond Compare tool still shows the differences between the two files.
Is there a way to eliminate differences shown based on the Alignment (but having the same content) in the Beyond Compare Tool?

I tried all the alignment options under 'Rules' in 'Beyond Compare' tool but that didn't really help.

Comment: That's not alignment, that's order of lines.

Answer (score 0):

To sort lines before comparison in Beyond Compare 4's Text Compare, click the dropdown on the right side of the **Format** toolbar button and select **Sorted**.